# Google Apps Script order of execution: why do functions get invoked merely by being defined?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Javascript, the following code will execute only once, but in Google Apps Script it executes twice (obviously the body and script tags would be omitted):

```
<body>
  <script>
    hi();
    function hi() {
      alert('hi')
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

In other words, in GoogleApps script merely defining a function invokes it. The following in Code.gs executes with undefined arguments passed to it.

```
function createQuery(keywords, dateRange) {
}
```

How can I define functions without them being called? Pointers to the docs would be helpful. I have scoured them without success.

Comment: it does not execute twice. show proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAS, you save and test functions using the toolbar at the top. By virtue of telling the function to run using the toolbar, you are calling the function. Any triggers that you have will also call it to run without 'calling' inside the code.

You can more minutely determine how and when a function runs by calling it later in the code. This can be done in nested functions or inside of other functions. Regardless of where you are defining the function, eventually you will have to either create a trigger or use the toolbar to run the function.

I'm not sure how you are experiencing a double call seeing as your reference code is not very in-depth. Keep in mind that to execute the script at all, you would have had to either set a trigger or run it yourself in which you are adding in an execution. If you execute code that tells itself to execute that same code, you would incur an infinite loop.

Users will be able to more accurately understand your question and issue and thus answer them should you provide more data and references. You may also want to read the references and guides on the basics of GAS and its use of Javascript.